# Write the following statements in symbolic form using either a universal quantifier or existential quantifier

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I just want to double check my work as I'm not entirely sure in my answers. If I got anything wrong please do tell me!

a) The equation $x^3 = 27$ has a natural number solution.

$$\exists x\in\mathbb{N},\ (x^3 = 27)$$

b) $0$ is less than or equal to every natural number.

$$\exists x\in\mathbb{N},\ (x \geq 0)$$

c) Every real number is rational.

$$\exists x\in\mathbb{R},\ (x\in\mathbb{Q})$$

Comment: Only (a) is correct. Basically, $\exists$ means "at least one" whereas $\forall$ means "every."

Comment: It would be very interesting to see the justification for the close vote, considering that the OP has provided work for every part of the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree - I wonder if somebody saw the list format and assumed it was a verbatim copy of an exercise. At any rate, I vote not to close (although I don't know if people here pay attention to such comments as they do on Mathoverflow).

Comment: I don't understand what you guys are talking about...

Comment: @Jake Someone has nominated your question to be "closed"/put "on hold", which would mean that no new answers can be posted. Brian and Matt (and I) don't see any reason for this, so we publicly wonder and state our disagreement.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the answer below has shown me what I did wrong. It was a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to (a) is correct, but the other two are not.

Your answer to (b) says in plain English that there is at least one natural number that is greater than or equal to $0$. You need the other quantifier: $\forall x\in\Bbb N(0\le x)$ says that $0$ is less than or equal to every natural number.

Your answer to (c) says that there is at least one real number that is rational. Here again you want the other quantifier: $\forall x\in\Bbb R(x\in\Bbb Q)$ says that every real number is rational.

Remember, you can always read $\forall x$ as *for all* $x$ *such that* or *for each* $x$ *such that*, and you can always read $\exists x$ as *there is at least one* $x$ *such that*.